# Where does meiosis II of oogenesis end exactly in tuba uterina - uterus?

Tags: homework, embryology

I know that metaphase II ends at ampulla tuba uterina, but I am not completely sure where the telophase II ends. Is it in the triangular section of cervix uterii?

I just have an intuition that the thing is not ending at the ampulla, since there is some time to get to the uterus. The thing must happen before implantation to the uterus, since the egg is blastocyst at the stage.

**2. When does meiosis II of oogenesis end exactly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location is exactly tuba uterina infundibulum, [source](http://www.embryology.ch/anglais/dbefruchtung/eisprung02.html), since the processes results in the following things before LH peak:

> - The correct placement of the uterine tube infundibulum upon the
>     ovarian surface
> - The rupture of the follicle wall and the flow of the
>     follicle fluid with the oocyte into the infundibulum
> - The inhibition of
>     the maturation of further follicles